# Loose coupling with Class.forName()

Tags: java, reflection, loose-coupling

```
interface Bank {
    void connect();
}

class SBI implements Bank {
    static{
        System.out.println("Hello from SBI static");
    }   
    public void connect() {
        System.out.println("Connected to SBI");
    }
}

class LooseCouplingTest {
    public static void main(String... args)throws Exception {
        String className = args[0];
        Class.forName(className);
    }
}
```

The output for the above code appears to be
`Hello from SBI static`

What should I add to my code and Y to `also` print the statement
`Connected to SBI`

In detail explanation is much appreciated

P.S. Noob here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a new instance of the object (using `Class#newInstance()`), cast it to the type you want (in your scenario `SBI`), and then call it.

**Working code:**

```
public class LooseCouplingTest {
    public static void main(String... args)throws Exception {
        String className = args[0];
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
        Object obj = clazz.newInstance();
        SBI mySBI = (SBI) obj;
        mySBI.connect();
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

- `Class.forName("pkg.SBI")` gets a reference for `pkg.SBI` class in the `clazz` object.
- As `clazz` holds a reference to `SBI`, calling `clazz.newInstance();` is the same as calling: `new SBI();`.
- After calling `clazz.newInstance();`, then, the variable `obj` will receive a `SBI` instance.
- As you want to call a `SBI` method and `obj`'s type is `Object` (that's the `newInstance()` method's return type) you have to cast it to `SBI` and only then call `connect()`.

### Using Java's Reflection API:

If you wish to go even further and not even do the cast (this way `LooseCouplingTest` never needs to import `SBI`), you can use **[Java's Reflection API](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-reflection-example/)** to invoke the `connect()` method.

**Here's the working code for that:**

```
public class LooseCouplingTest {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        String className = args[0];
        Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
        Object obj = clazz.newInstance();
        java.lang.reflect.Method connect = clazz.getMethod("connect");
        connect.invoke(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: @abcdjunior Thanks for your time.. can you give step by step explanation for why should we create a new instance of the object (using Class#newInstance()), cast it to the type we want and then call it?????????

Comment: @SnackySrikanth Yes: `Class.forName("pkg.SBI")` gets a reference for `pkg.SBI` class in the `clazz` object. As `clazz` holds a reference to `SBI`, calling `clazz.newInstance();` is the same as calling: `new SBI();`. After calling `clazz.newInstance();`, then, the variable `obj` will receive a `SBI` instance. Finally, as you want to call a `SBI` method and `obj`'s type is `Object` (that's the newInstance() method's return type) you have to cast it to `SBI` and only then call `connect()`. (I edited the answer to include this. Let me know if it is enough.)

Answer (score 1):

`Class.forName()` loads the class. and part of loading the class is executing the static initializer block. That's why you see "Hello from SBI static" printed (the `static { ... }` part is the static initializer block).

To make "Connected to SBI" appear, you have to create an instance of the class and call the `connect()` method on it:

```
Class<? extends Bank> bankClass = (Class<? extends Bank>)Class.forName(className);
Bank bank = bankClass.newInstance();
bank.connect();
```